# set both the HTTP Accept and Content-Type headers to "application/xml" in C#

Tags: c#, xml, json, wcf, c#-4.0

I created a web service (REST) in C#. Now I want that when someone uses it, it should return JSON or XML as per Header. I found a very good [tutorial here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/wcf-rest-xml-json-or-both). I followed it but I dont know where it says `set both the HTTP Accept and Content-Type headers to "application/xml"`, I am calling it in this way `http://localhost:38477/social/name`. I can answer to any question if my question is not very clear to you
Thanks
THis is my code

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "{Name}", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        public MyclassData Get(string Name)
        {
            // Code to implement
            return value;

        }
```

Comment: Are you already using the WebInvoke & WebGet attribute in your rest service, both these attributes have properties to set RequestFormat & ResponseFormat

Comment: @HatSoft Thank you,@Misha has pointed out the same thing but its not working

Comment: Please copy/paste the code here so we can help you further

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What framework are you using (Looks like the older WCf Web Api) to build your RESTful service? I would highly recommend using Microsofts new MVC4 Web API. It is really starting to mature and greatly simplifies building RESTful services. It is what is going to be supported in the future where the WCF Web API is about to be discontinued.

You simply return your ModelClass as a return type and it will automatically serialize it into XML or JSON depending on the requests accept header. You avoid having writing duplicate code and your service will support a wide range of clients.

```
public class TwitterController : ApiController
{
     DataScrapperApi api = new DataScrapperApi();
     TwitterAndKloutData data = api.GetTwitterAndKloutData(screenName);
     return data;
}

public class TwitterAndKloutData
{
   // implement properties here
}
```

**Links**

You can get MVC4 Web Api by downloading just MVC4 2012 RC or you can download the whole Visual Studio 2012 RC.

MVC 4: http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4

VS 2012: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads

---

For the original wcf web api give this a shot. Examine the accept header and generate your response according to its value.

```
var context = WebOperationContext.Current
string accept = context.IncomingRequest.Accept;
System.ServiceModel.Chanells.Message message = null;

if (accept == "application/json")
   message = context.CreateJsonResponse<TwitterAndCloutData>(data);
else if (accept == "text/xml")
   message = context.CreateXmlResponse<TwitterAndCloutData>(data);

return message;
```

---

You would set the accept header on whatever client is initiated the request. This will differ depending on what type of client you are using to send the request but any http  client will have a way to add headers.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("accept", "text/xml");
client.DownloadString("domain.com/service");
```

To access the response headers you would use

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
```

Additional resources: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/wcf-rest-xml-json-or-both

Comment: I respect your opinion,but I dont want to change my whole Service just because of this error.I mean I want to learn and know the answer of my question,surely next time I will be using MVC4..+1 for new Idea:)

Comment: @despertar - WCF infrastructure will automatically handle the request/response serialization/deserialization to correct format (json or xml) based on the Http headers. You do not need to handle that specifically (with any code) unless you are doing some additional work, which I don't think is what the question is asked for.

Comment: I write this in my function and now the return type doesn't matches.I don't want to change the return type...

Comment: @muruge You are very right..but the things is how to change the http header,in global.asax?

Comment: @muruge ah, yes, that sounds right. Been so long since I've used the older web api, thanks for the reminder +1. user - your http header is not something that is configured globally, is is a per-request deal. You may want text/plain on one method, and text/xml or application/json on another. as muruge said if you just remove the ResponseFormat.XML the Http Header should automatically be set to the appropriate type based on the request accept header.

Comment: @Despertar If you see my question ,the only thing that i asked was from where we can chnge the accept header and content type..The soltion you are giving me is actuallty my question

Comment: @user I added code to my answer showing where you would access the request headers for the client and the response headers for the server.

Comment: @Despertar still not working I put the code inside my function.I am really thankful to you for the effort you made :)

Comment: @Despertar the additional resource is in the question :)

Comment: @Despertar The last method you told orks fine for XML but not for JSON.I amm wondering why is it so,The JSON resposne also contain xmlns  at the top,Moreover I skipped the line client.DownloadString() as it has no use there

Comment: did you remove the responseFormat.XML attribute? can you edit your question with the full method and attributes you are using.

Answer (score 4):

You have specified the `RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml` in your `WebInvoke` attribute which restricts the format of both Request and Response to Xml. **Remove the RequestFormat and ResponseFormat** properties and let the framework work on it based on Http headers. **Content-type** header specifies the request body type and **Accept** header specifies the response body type.

**Edit:**

This is how you would send your requests using fiddler.

[image]

You could use **Microsoft.Http** and **Microsoft.Http.Extensions** dlls that comes with the [REST starter kit](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/WCF-REST-Starter-Kit-Download-125162.html) for writing client side code. Below is a sample.

```
        var client = new HttpClient("http://localhost:38477/social");
        client.DefaultHeaders.Accept.AddString("application/xml");
        client.DefaultHeaders.ContentType = "application/xml";
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.Get("twitter_name");
        var deserializedContent = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsDataContract<YourTypeHere>();
```

Comment: The things is where should we write this i-e Content-type and header?

Comment: The headers should be set in the client side when you send your requests. I will edit my answer to show how you could achieve this.

Comment: Do you think people will use fiddler to see the output?
Moreoever how i can see reponse in fiddler?

Comment: Fiddler is a great tool for debugging web services. Personally, I think it is one of the must have tools for developers working on the middle tier components of an application. To answer your question - You can go to the Inspectors tab to see the response.

Comment: @user1391118: Show us the code that you have tried out so we can help you fix it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13624/discussion-between-muruge-and-user1391118)

Answer (score -1):

Can you create two overloads for your method like this:

```
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "dostuff", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public StuffResponse DoStuff(RequestStuff requestStuff)


    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "dostuff", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    public StuffResponse DoStuff(RequestStuff requestStuff)
```

Comment: "Method not allowed. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service."

Comment: Ah sorry you need different parameters in the 2 methods for them to work.

Comment: I just implemented a single func,there is no parameter problem I think :)